# How to grab text values from getAllByTestId?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a component that lists a bunch of items. In this, they're cryptocurrency assets. When I click the header labelled `Name`, it sorts the items in alphabetical order. I would like to test this functionality by clicking the `Name` button in order to fire the event, and then asserting that the values in the name column are sorted alphabetically:

```
  it("Sorts by name on click", () => {
    const sortedByName = spotData
      .sort((a, b) => {
        return a.name < b.name ? -1 : a.name === b.name ? 0 : 1;
      })
      .map((ticker) => ticker.name);

    const { getByText, getAllByTestId } = renderWithProviders(
      <MarketSelectorPanel marketsList={spotData} />
    );

    fireEvent.click(getByText("Name"));
    expect(getAllByTestId("market-selector-row-name")).toEqual(
      sortedByName
    );
  });
```

The above doesn't work because `expect(getAllByTestId("market-selector-row-name"))` grabs the entire HTML element:

● MarketSelectorPanel tables › Sorts by name on click

```
expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

- Expected
+ Received

  Array [
-   "BCH/USD",
-   "BTC/USD",
-   "ETH/USD",
+   <span
+     class="market-selector-row-val"
+     data-testid="market-selector-row-name"
+   >
+     BCH/USD
+   </span>,
+   <span
+     class="market-selector-row-val"
+     data-testid="market-selector-row-name"
+   >
+     BTC/USD
+   </span>,
+   <span
+     class="market-selector-row-val"
+     data-testid="market-selector-row-name"
+   >
+     ETH/USD
+   </span>
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved using `getNodeText`:

```
const columnAfterClick = getAllByTestId("market-selector-row-name").map(getNodeText); // Contains array of text strings only now

expect(columnAfterClick).toEqual(sortedByName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try passing the XPath of the component for testing rather than the id